# How to save the content of Textbox into a textfile

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textbox, openfiledialog

I have a textbox which has some content. I also have a button (SAVE) which shud open the FileSaveDialog and allow the content to be saved in a .txt file.

XAML:

```
<TextBox Height="93" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Path=ReadMessage, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="MessageRead" />

<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding Path=SaveFileCommand}" Name="I2CSaveBtn" />
```

ViewModel:

```
private string _readMessage = string.Empty;
    public string ReadMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return _readMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            _readMessage = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ReadMessage");
        }
    }

public static RelayCommand SaveFileCommand { get; set; }

private void RegisterCommands()
    {            
        SaveFileCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.ExecuteSaveFileDialog());
    }
private void ExecuteSaveFileDialog()
    {
        //What To Do HERE???
    }
```

What I basically need is to read the content of textbox, open a file save dialog and store it in a text file to be saved in my system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx#Common_Dialogs) you could do something along these lines

```
string fileText = ReadMessage; 

SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog() 
{ 
    Filter = "Text Files(*.txt)|*.txt|All(*.*)|*" 
}; 

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true) 
{ 
     File.WriteAllText(dialog.FileName, fileText); 
}
```

Comment: Might want to check if the file already exists / do you want to overwrite etc....

Comment: yeah. it works smoothly :) How abt opening a dialog in order to load a textfile?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
   saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text file|*.txt";
   saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Image File";
   saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

   // If the file name is not an empty string open it for saving.
   if(saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
   {
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, MessageRead.Text);
}
```

Comment: You should rather check if `ShowDialog` returns `true`.

Comment: Ok. This is how it was on MSDN, so I always took it for granted.